# Compilation-error while passing Variant argument ByRef in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a "compilation" error in Excel VBA, which I don't understand...

I've got a method like that :

```
    Public Sub SomeMethod(ByRef argument As SomeClass)
        ... <- 'argument' must be called ByRef because I have to modify it
    End Sub
```

If I define a variable like :

```
    Dim var As SomeClass
```

No problem, I can call :

```
    SomeMethod var
```

and it's working.

BUT, if I define a Variant variable like :

```
    Dim var as Variant
    Set var = New SomeClass
```

It doesn't work.

If I call :

```
    SomeMethod var
```

VB pops-up a message : **'ByRef argument type mismatch'**

If I call :

```
    SomeMethod (var)
```

it "compiles", but var is then passed ByVar and it gave me a runtime-error message : **'Object doesn't support this property or method'**

So I basically just want to tell VBA that my Variant variable 'var' is in fact a 'SomeClass' object (in debugger, VBA says so), but I don't know how to do that...

Could someone please help me ?

Comment: Why does it need to be a Variant at all? If you know it's of type `SomeClass`, then declare it as such.

Comment: My whole code is in a full VBA project and the `var` object could be of multiples types.

Comment: My whole code is in a full VBA project and the `var` object could be of multiples types. And depending of its type (`TypeName var`), I must call a specific method which has typed argument (`Method_A(ByRef arg as SomeClass` or `Method_B(ByRef arg as SomeOtherClass)`)

Comment: "Even if a called procedure has declared its parameters as ByRef, you can force those to be ByVal by enclosing each argument within parentheses." -- http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorate the argument with `ByVal`

```
Public Sub SomeMethod(ByVal argument As someclass)
```

then you can pass a variant;

```
SomeMethod var
```

This works because the `ByVal argument` is received as a local *copy* of a reference to a `Variant[someclass]` which means VB can freely perform a type-conversion (to convert the `Variant[someclass]->someclass`).

It wont work when passed as `ByRef` because any changes to `argument` would also affect the calling object reference variable outside the current procedure.

If you pass `As Object` you don't need the `ByVal`.

If your doing this a lot with custom classes VBA supports interfaces; `function foo(obj as IOneOfMyWidgets)`

Comment: I think he wants ByRef so that changes to argument **do** affect the variable in the calling procedure (cf the comment in his first code snippet).

Comment: If you pass an object byref/val changes are *always* reflected as its the same reference that's being passed, so your always working with the same instance of the object in the caller and callee. Using byval simply allows `As Variant` as the argument can be freely reassigned after type conversion at runtime without affecting anything else.

Comment: @Alex K. : thank you for the clarification on passing ByRef / ByVal object references. It now works fine with ByVal ! I still think that the VBA syntax is too 'opaque' with pointer/reference convention, so I didn't understand it earlier...

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

### Proper way to call a Sub

In VBA, to call a Sub, you can either write this

```
SomeSub var
```

without parentheses or this

```
Call SomeSub(var)
```

This: `SomeSub (var)` doesn't do what you think it does.

### Casting Variant to class or data type

As I was writing this, Alex K's answer came in, so I will just supplement by showing that the type mismatch isn't restricted to objects, but also affects primitive data types contained in a Variant:

```
Sub tester()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = 1.234567 ' v is now type Variant/Double
    dothis v ' No problem.
    dothat v ' Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch.
End Sub

Sub dothis(ByVal d As Double)
    'stuff
End Sub

Sub dothat(ByRef d As Double)
    'stuff    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, I now understand how Variant objects are kept in memory... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also explicitly cast to a type:

```
'/* Factory */
Select Case TypeName(var)
    Case "SomeClass":
        Dim cast As SomeClass
        Set cast = var
        SomeMethod cast
End Select
```